# GraphQL Apollo Server, how to make a field register an empty string as null

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I have a nullable field 'language' which is actually never null. It's either a locale code, or an empty string ''. This causes issues on my client which expects either a locale code or nothing at all.

Although I could catch this in my client, or prevent this in my database, I'd prefer handling this issue in my GQL server.

One solution I could think of is to check the data I receive in my datasources and to mutate if necessary. However I fear this might harm performance as this is a very critical query and I don't want to use this check every time someone accesses any page on my website.

Comment: fix database entries using db tools/console

Comment: That is a temporary solution. Also I'd like to catch incorrect db entries like this, and handle them accordingly.

Comment: update API to not accept empty strings?

Comment: That is what this question is for, my GQL server is directly on the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would provide a custom resolver for the field in question:

```
const resolvers = {
  SomeType: {
    language (parent) => {
      return parent.language || null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Very clean solution. I should've realised how easy a resolver would be for this. Until now I had no idea empty strings returned false in boolean expressions, so that's good to know too. Thanks!

Comment: masking problem only ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Custom scalars and enums](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/scalars-enums/#validations) can be used to make some customization, f.e. validation or autocorrection converting provided data (`""` into `null`).

[Keystone.JS](https://www.keystonejs.com/api/hooks/#validateinput) has a nice system of hooks for that.